# OR-Tools Vehicle Routing with Multiple Trips, Multiple Pickup and limited capacity

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to solve a routing problem as follows:

- We have many 'tasks' and each task contains many items to be collected by workers
- items can appear in multiple tasks (e.g. item 1 can be in both task A and B)
- We already have the distance matrix of the items
- depot is fixed
- in each trip, each worker can ONLY collect **items in AT MOST 3 tasks** (business domain constraint)

My question is how to use or-tools to implement a solver that:

- allows each worker to "unload" the items collected at the depot and continue to next trip
- set a constraint that limits workers to collect items in at most 3 tasks

So far I have tried:

- treat same items appearing in n tasks as n different nodes (reflected in the distance matrix, and the distance among these n nodes are set to 0)
- uses pickup and deliveries to model each task, so one item in each task will be pointed by other items in within the same task. And create a capacity constraint of 3 and set the demand of that node as 1. (e.g. task A contains [1, 2, 3, 4]. I add pickup and deliveries [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]. Then create a capacity constraint of 3 for each worker, and set node 4 a demand of 1.) But adding this seems to kill the jupyter notebook kernal. (Removing this the code can run.)

Sorry for such a long question, thanks and please help!

**Update: I made use of AddDisjunction and AddPickupAndDelivery and the results seem to be what I expected. I am not 100% sure if this is the answer to this problem. I am treating same items appearing in different tasks as different nodes. And add the whole set of items in each task as a disjunction set. For pickup and delivery, I didn't duplicate the nodes, I simply make each item points to the same 1 item in that task.**

The code I wrote (updated):

```py
    # "order" is the same as a "task"
    data = {
        'distance_matrix': get_distance_matrix(locations),
        'demands': demands,
        'num_workers': number_of_order_groups,
        'max_num_orders': [num_orders_in_group] * number_of_order_groups,
        'disjunctions': disjunctions,
        'depot': 0,
    }

    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_workers'], data['depot'])

    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['max_num_orders'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')

    for d in data['disjunctions']:
        routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(i) for i in d], 100000000, d.shape[0])

    for d in data['disjunctions']:
        for i in d[:-1]:
            routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(manager.NodeToIndex(i), manager.NodeToIndex(d[-1]))

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.AUTOMATIC
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.AUTOMATIC

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)

    else:
        print('No solution found !')
```

The result I got:

```
Objective: 4329
Route for worker 0:
 0 Load(0) ->  49 Load(0.0) ->  64 Load(0.0) ->  48 Load(0.0) ->  50 Load(0.0) ->  62 Load(0.0) ->  46 Load(0.0) ->  47 Load(0.0) ->  63 Load(0.0) ->  67 Load(0.0) ->  51 Load(0.0) ->  52 Load(1.0) ->  66 Load(1.0) ->  65 Load(2.0) ->  68 Load(2.0) ->  69 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 421m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 1:
 0 Load(0) ->  178 Load(0.0) ->  163 Load(0.0) ->  179 Load(0.0) ->  136 Load(0.0) ->  137 Load(0.0) ->  160 Load(0.0) ->  170 Load(0.0) ->  143 Load(0.0) ->  183 Load(0.0) ->  145 Load(0.0) ->  144 Load(0.0) ->  181 Load(0.0) ->  169 Load(0.0) ->  132 Load(0.0) ->  165 Load(0.0) ->  167 Load(0.0) ->  182 Load(0.0) ->  138 Load(0.0) ->  140 Load(0.0) ->  166 Load(0.0) ->  133 Load(0.0) ->  168 Load(0.0) ->  172 Load(0.0) ->  161 Load(0.0) ->  171 Load(0.0) ->  142 Load(0.0) ->  162 Load(0.0) ->  164 Load(0.0) ->  139 Load(0.0) ->  175 Load(0.0) ->  159 Load(0.0) ->  177 Load(0.0) ->  134 Load(0.0) ->  173 Load(1.0) ->  135 Load(1.0) ->  141 Load(1.0) ->  146 Load(2.0) ->  176 Load(2.0) ->  180 Load(2.0) ->  184 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 752m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 2:
 0 Load(0) ->  34 Load(0.0) ->  24 Load(0.0) ->  21 Load(0.0) ->  29 Load(0.0) ->  2 Load(0.0) ->  19 Load(0.0) ->  25 Load(0.0) ->  8 Load(0.0) ->  5 Load(0.0) ->  20 Load(0.0) ->  9 Load(0.0) ->  11 Load(0.0) ->  13 Load(0.0) ->  1 Load(0.0) ->  10 Load(0.0) ->  14 Load(0.0) ->  7 Load(0.0) ->  3 Load(0.0) ->  27 Load(0.0) ->  4 Load(0.0) ->  189 Load(0.0) ->  31 Load(0.0) ->  32 Load(0.0) ->  15 Load(0.0) ->  6 Load(0.0) ->  23 Load(0.0) ->  33 Load(0.0) ->  22 Load(0.0) ->  12 Load(0.0) ->  28 Load(0.0) ->  26 Load(0.0) ->  16 Load(1.0) ->  190 Load(1.0) ->  30 Load(1.0) ->  35 Load(2.0) ->  191 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 730m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 3:
 0 Load(0) ->  109 Load(0.0) ->  110 Load(0.0) ->  148 Load(0.0) ->  111 Load(0.0) ->  112 Load(0.0) ->  147 Load(0.0) ->  149 Load(0.0) ->  150 Load(1.0) ->  113 Load(2.0) ->  157 Load(2.0) ->  158 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 214m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 4:
 0 Load(0) ->  117 Load(0.0) ->  129 Load(0.0) ->  127 Load(0.0) ->  76 Load(0.0) ->  123 Load(0.0) ->  71 Load(0.0) ->  122 Load(0.0) ->  115 Load(0.0) ->  119 Load(0.0) ->  125 Load(0.0) ->  74 Load(0.0) ->  73 Load(0.0) ->  72 Load(0.0) ->  130 Load(0.0) ->  116 Load(0.0) ->  120 Load(0.0) ->  124 Load(0.0) ->  70 Load(0.0) ->  75 Load(0.0) ->  118 Load(0.0) ->  128 Load(0.0) ->  77 Load(1.0) ->  126 Load(1.0) ->  131 Load(2.0) ->  121 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 521m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 5:
 0 Load(0) ->  95 Load(0.0) ->  99 Load(0.0) ->  96 Load(0.0) ->  92 Load(0.0) ->  98 Load(0.0) ->  88 Load(0.0) ->  97 Load(0.0) ->  107 Load(0.0) ->  94 Load(0.0) ->  55 Load(0.0) ->  106 Load(0.0) ->  83 Load(0.0) ->  102 Load(0.0) ->  93 Load(0.0) ->  81 Load(0.0) ->  87 Load(0.0) ->  79 Load(0.0) ->  80 Load(0.0) ->  90 Load(0.0) ->  58 Load(0.0) ->  57 Load(0.0) ->  86 Load(0.0) ->  154 Load(0.0) ->  101 Load(0.0) ->  85 Load(0.0) ->  84 Load(0.0) ->  105 Load(0.0) ->  91 Load(0.0) ->  153 Load(0.0) ->  155 Load(0.0) ->  56 Load(0.0) ->  100 Load(0.0) ->  104 Load(0.0) ->  82 Load(0.0) ->  54 Load(0.0) ->  151 Load(0.0) ->  59 Load(1.0) ->  89 Load(1.0) ->  103 Load(1.0) ->  152 Load(1.0) ->  108 Load(2.0) ->  156 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 721m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 6:
 0 Load(0) ->  41 Load(0.0) ->  114 Load(1.0) ->  39 Load(1.0) ->  40 Load(1.0) ->  43 Load(1.0) ->  38 Load(1.0) ->  42 Load(1.0) ->  44 Load(2.0) ->  185 Load(2.0) ->  186 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 369m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 7:
 0 Load(0) ->  78 Load(1.0) ->  60 Load(1.0) ->  61 Load(2.0) ->  187 Load(2.0) ->  188 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 231m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 8:
 0 Load(0) ->  174 Load(1.0) ->  36 Load(1.0) ->  37 Load(2.0) ->  17 Load(2.0) ->  18 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 198m
Load of the route: 3.0

Route for worker 9:
 0 Load(0) ->  192 Load(1.0) ->  53 Load(2.0) ->  45 Load(3.0) ->  0 Load(3.0)
Distance of the route: 172m
Load of the route: 3.0

Total distance of all routes: 4329m
Total load of all routes: 30.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my final solution for anybody who is working on a similar setting problem:

1. allows each vehicle to "unload" the items collected at the depot and continue to next trip
2. set a constraint that limits workers to collect items in at most 3 tasks

For 1, I simply set the number of vehicles to be equal the number of tasks. The solution found should contains a lot of vehicles with no items. Our business use case allows workers to move onto next route once he/she has finished the current route so there's no need to mimic "loading/unloading" in ortools.

For 2, since each task has multiple items. I used a list to represent items for a particular task, e.g.:

```py
items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then all the items are represented by a list of list, and 0 is the depot, e.g.:

```py
items = [[0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8], [9, 10]] # we have 4 tasks here
demands = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] # all items have 0 demand for now
```

The key is to created a dummy node for each task and set its demand to 1:

```py
items = [[0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 11], [5, 6, 7, 12], [8, 13], [9, 10, 14]] # we have 4 tasks here
demands = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] # dummy nodes have 1 demand
```

add capacity constraint:

```py
# define demand callback function (demand is the cost of a node)
def demand_callback(from_index):
    """Returns the demand of the node."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    return data['demands'][from_node]

demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(demand_callback)

# associate demand to max_num_orders
routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
    demand_callback_index,
    0,  # null capacity slack
    data['max_num_orders'],  # worker maximum capacities, 3 in our case
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    'Capacity')
```

Then create pickup and delivery constraints, where the pickup nodes are the **REAL** items and the delivery nodes are the **DUMMIES**:

```py
# [1:] because we don't care about the depot
for d in data['items'][1:]:
    for i in d[:-1]:
        pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(i)
        delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(d[-1])
        routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
        routing.solver().Add(routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(delivery_index))
```

AddDisjunction is no longer required as my problem always has a feasible solution without dropping any node. You might add disjunctions if your problem might requires  dropping nodes to get a solution.

That's it.

If your solver get stuck finding the solution. Try to change your first solution strategy to PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC as this strategy always (I think) gives you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unload/Multitrip
   For unload you have to duplicate the depot node and add a negative demand to simulate the "unloading" (with a slackvar used to reset to zero if you unload too much)
   see: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py

OR you can increase the vehicle fleet and see each vehicle route as a "trip" that you can assign to any worker. i.e. each worker may be "assigned" to several vehicle route.
note: if you have time constraint you can add some constraint like `time_dimension.Cumulvar(End_N) <= time_dimension.CumulVar(Start_N+1)`

2. Task limitation
   For tasks limit, I need to think about it, from top of my head I would try

- Create a counter dimension for each task.
- For each item location, add +1 to the corresponding task

So now if you are looking at each vehicle end node.
You can know the number of tasks the vehicle did by counting the non zero task dimension.
So adding a constraint to limit this to be at most 3 should make it IMHO

Work In Progress pseudo code:

```py
# List of tasks
tasks = ("TaskA", "TaskB", "TaskC", ...)
# Task demands 1 if locations index belongs to the task, 0 otherwise
task_demands = {}
task_demands["TaskA"] = (0, 0, 1, 0, ...)
task_demands["TaskB"] = (0, 1, 1, 0, ...)
...

# Creates tasks demand callbacks and register them
# note: this is similar to any capacity dimension example
tasks_demand_evaluator_index = {}
for task in tasks:
  def task_demand(index):
    node = manager.IndexToNode(index)
    return task_demands[task][node]
   
  tasks_demand_evaluator_index[task] = 
    routing.registerUnaryTransitCallback(task_demand)


# create task dimensions
for task in tasks:
  routing.AddDimension(
    tasks_demand_evaluator_index[task],
    0,
    LARGE_ENOUGH,
    True, # start at zero
    task # dimension name
  )

solver = routing.solver()
for vehicle in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
  end = routing.End(vehicle)
  performed_tasks = []
  for task in tasks:
    dim = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(task)
    has_done_this_task = dim.CumulVar(end) > 0 # only true if vehicle visit an item associated to this task
    performed_tasks.append(has_done_this_task)
  solver.Add(solver.Sum(performed_tasks) <= 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed suggestion. I haven't tried your it yet but moments before I saw your answer, I have tried to use Disjunction and Pickup and Deliveries and the results seem to be correct. I am very new to or-tools and I would like you to take a look, I have edited my question with the current code and output. Thanks

Comment: I might have been not very clear, I can understand your solution, but it is checking if any vehicle has visited items in 3 different tasks. The actual problem has 1 more constraint, that is when a vehicle has visited an item, it has to visit the remaining items in the same task.

Comment: for same vehicle constraint take a look at https://gist.github.com/Mizux/9e37c370a459bd472a6ac13c304f0b54
note: If you have extra constraints you didn't write in the question, it will be difficult for us to answer them ;)